# How to make fonts available to the system

Tags: linux-mint, fonts

I'm using Android Studio, and in the drop down list of fonts is Source Code Pro.  On that list, the font looks quite nice, but the preview below (and what I get when I select it) is horrible.  I'm using "size 14". I thought perhaps that Android Studio is using a bitmap for that text, rather than rendering it, and I couldn't find any evidence the font was installed as the System Settings part of Linux Mint KDE 13 doesn't offer it in any lists of fonts, so I downloaded it, copied the files (.otf.woff and .ttf.woff format) into

```
/usr/share/fonts/truetype
```

then ran

```
fc-cache -fv
```

Part of the output of this is:

```
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/sourcecodepro: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
```

Suggesting it's not recognizing it.

I've even rebooted (Windows habits die hard) but I can't see this font anywhere other than in Android Studio.

Am I doing something wrong in how I install this font?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to directly install web font in Mint (Ubuntu/Debian based).

- If those font are in real format TTF or OTF than remove `.woff` extension from their names. (leave only known extensions `.ttf` or `.otf`)
- Otherwise, use [woff2otf](https://github.com/hanikesn/woff2otf) to convert them first.

**Reference:** [How to convert WOFF to TTF/OTF via command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017922/how-to-convert-woff-to-ttf-otf-via-command-line)